# Split a word by a char in Java

Tags: java, string, split

Consider the following example. I would like to divide the String into two parts by the char 'T'

```
// input
String toDivideStr = "RaT15544";

// output
first= "RaT";
second = "15544";
```

I've tried this:

```
String[] first = toDivideStr.split("T",0);
```

Output:

```
first = "Ra"
second = "15544"
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to to, is locate the last "T", then split:

```
StringToD.substring(StringToD.lastIndexOf("T") + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a positive lookahead to assert a digit and a positive lookbehind to assert `RaT`.

```
(?<=RaT)(?=\\d)
```

For example:

```
String str = "RaT15544";
for (String element : str.split("(?<=RaT)(?=\\d)"))
    System.out.println(element);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZoTQWx/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/OcHqld)

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive look-ahead with `split` limit parameter for this. `(?=\\d)`

With only `T` in the split method parameter, what happens is the regex engine consumes this `T`. Hence the two string split that occurs doesn't have `T`. To avoid consuming the characters, we can use non-consumeing look-ahead.

`(?=\\d)` - This will match the first number that is encountered but it will not consume this number

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String s = "RaT15544";
    String[] ss = s.split("(?=\\d)", 2);
    System.out.println(ss[0] + " " + ss[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below `regex` can be used to split the alphabets and numbers separately.

```
String StringToD = "RaT15544";
String[] parts = StringToD.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
System.out.println(parts[0]);
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```